# Run script on any selected text

Tags: script, python

I have a Python script that reads text from a file, processes and saves it to new file.

When I want to process some text on a webpage I need to copy & paste to a file, save, run the script, open the second file, and finally copy to the webpage.

Is there any way to script or automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could monitor the clipboard and run a script on the text stored there when it changes.

easiest way is to just use tkinter. it will open a empty form while running though.

```
import tkinter as Tk
form = Tk.Tk()
previousData = form.clipboard_get()
while True:
    data = form.clipboard_get()
    if data != previousData:
        processData(data)
        previousData = data
```

Comment: Will not this script slow down OS?